# JavaScript Isotope: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I receive the following error when Using ***JavaScript Isotope***.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined
```

Tracing to the following line of code:

```
isotope.$filteredAtoms.each(function (i, elem)
```

And, if necessary for trouble shooting - the surrounding code:

```js
var isotope = $('.filter-container').data('isotope');
function addEvenClasses()
{
    // add even classes to every other visible item, in current order
    isotope.$filteredAtoms.each(function (i, elem)
    {
        $(elem)[(i%2 ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass')]('even');
    });
}
```

I am sure the fix is simple, I'm just not seeing it. Also, I am new to using Isotope :]

Comment: That means `$filteredAtoms` is undefined. Do you have a better example?  From the docs: isotopeInstance.$filteredAtoms: 'jQuery object of filtered & sorted item elements'. Are you sure there are item elements?

Comment: I used the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/QsCZx

And, of coursed mixed the code into my environment and received this error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the v1 or v2 of isotope? 
v1 is used in the jsfiddle demo you mention you copied your code from:
http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/QsCZx
uses
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/jquery.isotope.min.js

But the latest release version is v2.
https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/blob/master/dist/isotope.pkgd.js

From what I can see, `$filteredAtoms` doesn't exist in the v2 version.

It looks like it may have been replaced with `$filteredItems`, so you could try using that.

Answer (score 0):

replace `$` to the `jQuery` I think that error is not in the isotop